# Issues with dplyr and ggplot2 on summarizing data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have an issue when trying to use dplyr and ggplot2 to summarize data. I have a data set(excel file) that I imported:

```
df<-read.xlsx('sample.xlsx', sheet = 1)
```

With a sample of the data

```
        date  user          vert  aff        browser clicks age    rpc installs  revenue   Week    Month   Year
1 2017-10-25 2017-10-25   maps_1  appfocus1  Chrome     13   0 0.4436       37   5.7668     43      10   2017
2 2017-10-25 2017-10-25   maps_1  appfocus1  Chrome   1140   0 0.4436     2914 505.7040     43      10   2017
3 2017-10-25 2017-10-25     maps appfocus84  Chrome   2189   0 0.4436     7543 971.0404     43      10   2017
4 2017-10-25 2017-10-25   maps_1  appfocus1 Firefox      1   0 0.4436        6   0.4436     43      10   2017
5 2017-10-25 2017-10-25   maps_1  appfocus1 Firefox    123   0 0.4436      170  54.5628     43      10   2017
6 2017-10-25 2017-10-25     maps appfocus84 Firefox    331   0 0.4436      497 146.8316     43      10   2017
         source
1 googlepartner
2        search
3          NULL
4 googlepartner
5        search
6          NULL
```

The code below takes a column "affiliate" and generate the summation of two fields based on that column. Then I create a calculated field by "affiliate":

```
UC10 <- filter(df, UCMonth == 10)

UC101 <- UC10 %>% group_by(affiliate) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(revenue,installs),sum)%>%
  mutate(RPI = revenue/installs)
```

And get the below data:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  affiliate  revenue installs    RPI
  <chr>        <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 appfocus1   53603.   809580 0.0662
2 appfocus84 174479.  2768181 0.0630
```

Then I try to plot, by affiliate, the total RPI using ggplot2:

```
gcor <- ggplot(UC101, aes(x = affiliate, y = RPI)) +
  geom_boxplot(color = "dark red")
```

My problem is the output of the graph. When I look at the graph, I get the below error:

[image]

Can anyone help understand why it isn't showing a full boxplot? This is really my first time using dplyr and ggplot2 together, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a bar plot instead of a boxplot?   If so you might want `geom_col()`.  A boxplot is a summary of the distribution of the data, so you'll need more than a single value per group if you want to make one.

Comment: Thank you!! That helps a ton!! I really do appreciate that!!